# Why was a git commit created by a pull?

Tags: git, github, merge, commit

I was merging a developer branch into our main developer branch when I encountered a merge conflict.  I did a `git merge --abort` to abort the merge and talked to the other developer.  The other developer fixed the issue and successfully merging the main dev branch into his feature.  Then he pushed his changes to the remote repo.  I pulled the changes (via the Github application) and a new commit was created for some reason.  The commit history (both my local repo and the remote repo) now looks like this:

- Me ---- Hash# -- Merge branch `xyz_feature` of `remote repo name` into `xyz_feature`
- Them -- Hash# -- Merge branch `dev_branch` into `xyz_feature`
- ... (More commits) ...

Also, my new mysterious commit contains 58 changed files with 2341 additions and 294 deletions.

What happened here?  Do I need to remove this new commit?

Edit: I did a folder diff on both commits.  There are no differences.  However the mysterious commit shows lots of changes between these two commits.  Why the discrepancy?

Comment: A pull merges the upstream changes. When you encountered a merge conflict, the pull/merge was halted but not aborted or undone. So now you are simply seeing the "completed" merge that you started when you pulled. That is normal nothing to worry about.

Comment: Even though I did a `git merge --abort` to avoid that?  (note: question updated)

Comment: So .. now you are seeing the merge commit from your pull after the problem was fixed, right?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing that.  I'm happy to accept this, I'm just confused by the additional and subtractions in the new commit.  Shouldn't it show no changes (because it happened after the other developer's merge?)  Note: I added that to the question.

Comment: It seems like you are just getting all the new changes from `dev_branch` being merged into `xyz_branch`. That could include a lot more than just "the fix" you expect to see (which I think should be at least one expected change).

Comment: Show the commit graph and all shall be revealed. Without a graph one would just be guessing.